# security implementation for site search

Tags: php, mysql, security, search

I  am going to write site search with php/mysql,but I don't have any experience of writing code for security for this.
And therefore I need your advice(also examples and links).

How can I implement logic that limits the number of request that come from a specific IP in a given time and logic that makes sure search request is coming from your site and not 3rd party.

Thank's

Comment: It's because you ask questions, get answers, and don't accept those answers. Which means people don't get the reputation they deserve on StackOverflow. Just go through your old questions and mark answers as such.

Comment: It's the way you show appreciation towards other developers here. If you don't accept / vote up answers, you seem unthankful.

Comment: Yes , but we will don't concentrate only for voting ,isn't it?

Comment: And now, it's seem me that you like more conversation about voting than about my question (((

Comment: @newprog dood just select the checkmark next to answers you used... that's how the site is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

*Number of requests* - create a separate table where you will store IP adress and datetime of request - when COUNT of rows for specific IP and some period of time is greater than limit - deny access

*3rd party sites* - as far as i know the best solution is blacklist.